# How to transpile a Dart lib to a JavaScript one?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

If I develop a Dart library, is there an idiom to ***transpile*** the Dart library to a JavaScript one?

Assume the Dart library mainly exports two things: a class and a function. On JavaScript side, a JavaScript class/object and a function are expected.

---

**UPDATE**

What I expect can be addressed in this scenario: I define a class *ArrayList* in my Dart lib (the directive *library* and the kerword *export* are used), and then I use some way to transpile this Dart lib to a JavaScript lib, in which there's some definition like: *function ArrayList() { ... }* . Thus, in a client JavaScript one can use it like: *var a = new ArrayList()* .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dart2js
Usage: dart2js [options] dartfile

Compiles Dart to JavaScript.

Common options:
  -o <file> Generate the output into <file>.
  -c        Insert runtime type checks and enable assertions (checked mode).
  -m        Generate minified output.
  -h        Display this message (add -v for information about all options).
```

If you have a `pub package` (with `pubspec.yaml`), then you can just run

```
pub build
```

to get the whole package to be transpiled to JavaScript (and transformers being run that are used by some frameworks for code generation)

Comment: Thank you Günter Zöchbauer. I'd tried dart2js; so, a whole closure calling is result, and I need to clean it manually? cause I don't see the same class name and function name or similar ones exposed in the output js as in the Dart file.

Comment: Not sure what your comment is about. The output is not supposed to contain any classes. The output is ES5, tree-shaken and minimized.

Comment: I mean I used dart2js on my library, and its output basically is (function() {...})(). my js is here: https://repl.it/Iq37/0 . ArrayList is the class name defined in my lib.

Comment: What do you expect the file to contain?

Comment: I expect there's a js output containing some object definition like: function ArrayList() { ... }. And in a client js one can use the object like: var a = new ArrayList() .

Comment: Dart-to-JS transpilation only does whole-application transpilation. You can't use this code easily from JS code for example. You can use dart-js-interop to make certain identifiers available to JS, but without that tree-shaking and minification makes it impossible to use the code from JS. It's supposed to be added using a script tag and then executed automatically. There is some experimental DDC (Dart Development Compiler) that produces readable ES6 output, but currently it's only supposed to be used for development.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147095/discussion-between-xando-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to chat. If you have further questions (in comments) I'll try to answer.

Comment: The update in your question isn't a well supported use case with Dart. See my 2nd last comment.